# Odoo -how to list down all the button for particular module

Tags: odoo-8

Is the any possibilities to fetch list of buttons for a particular module..like field(Ir_model_fields),i want to list down all the buttons and fields for the particular module in my module..

i have three field in my module..

```
module_id:fields.many2one('ir.model','Module'),
field_id:fields.many2one('ir.model.fields','Fields',domain="
[('model_id','=',module_id)]")
```

if i choose any module name...i can able to get the list of fields of that particular  in field_id using this code,likewise how can i get for button

Comment: if you want to get list of field of that model you need to use one2many not many2one and what you mean by get list of buttons exaclty do you means button tags?

Comment: i mean in for i have buttons right ..so what are all buttons in that module we have that list